# How can I run local applications through firejail?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, firejail

I've installed debian package locally. I randomly chose Opera, extracted via `dkpg -x opera-x.y.z.deb ~/bin/opera_package`, and created a symlink in my user's `~/bin` folder (which is in the user's path).

Attempting to run in side firejail

```
$ firejail opera

Reading profile /etc/firejail/opera.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-mgmt.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-secret.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Parent pid 14762, child pid 14763

Child process initialized
/bin/bash: opera: command not found

parent is shutting down, bye...
```

If I try to run using absolute path (from my home folder):

```
$ firejail /bin/local_packages/opera/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera
Reading profile /etc/firejail/opera.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Parent pid 15796, child pid 15797
Child process initialized
/bin/bash: /bin/local_packages/opera/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera: No such file or directory

Parent is shutting down, bye...
```

The browser GUI never starts up and the CLI reports the process DOA. I'm assuming I need to adjust the `disable-common.inc`

```
# grep -Rin 'bin' .
./disable-common.inc:125:# The user ~/bin directory can override commands such as ls
./disable-common.inc:126:read-only ${HOME}/bin
```

**My Question(s):**

- How can I run local applications through firejail?
- Is there a profile for local apps?
- Do I need to edit disable-common.profile?
- Is there a CL option to allow folders?
- Do I just select a different folder than `~/bin/`?

**My Goals:**

I'd like to...

1. sandbox applications cloned from github.com after they are compiled
2. keep both source and binary in my user folder
3. not have to `sudo` at any point (outside of installing `firejail`)

Comment: What happens if you specify the full path to opera? -- `firejail $(which opera)`

Comment: @BartonChittenden, I updated my question. THe same thing appears to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Firejail should certainly be able to do this out of the box, and I'm using it this way myself. Try running `firejail bash` and checking if it sees the executables in question. Also, `opera` may be a shell script that sets up an environment and runs another binary that turns out to be hidden by `firejail`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation supplied for firejail is available [here](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/). It unfortunately is not very comprehensive and is more like a user guide.

The [answer from L29Ah](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385161) supplied me enough information to figure out how to do this, but it is unfortunate that the answer doesn't give useful examples and more information. So I will try to answer all the questions and show some real ways to do this.

- **Is there a profile for local apps?** From looking [at the source code](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/blob/2cbffc072197b72ac234b969d77ab9c1def41f1d/src/firejail/util.c#L613), firejail extracts the command name from the first argument in the command line you tell it to run in the following way: first, it truncates the string value of that argument at the first whitespace character it finds, and then it drops any leading directory components in the path. So the command 'firejail  /home/me/various/"commandName  commandNameSecondWord" ' would search for a profile called "commandName.profile". There is no special processing for programs which are run from under $HOME versus a system directory like /usr/bin. It is also possible to bypass all of that by using one or more "--profile=..." options on the command line.
- **Do I need to edit disable-common.profile?** No. First, I do not recommend editing this file since it is included by other firejail profiles. Secondly, I did not have a problem running my particular local program even with this file included. Thirdly, if somehow something in that file is a problem, then you should be writing a custom profile which doesn't include it, and if you want some parts of it anyway, just copy them into your custom profile.
- **Do I just select a different folder than ~/bin/?** No, it's more complicated.
- **Is there a CL option to allow folders?** Yes, there are many ways to do this. Ordinarily, however, you would write a profile for the particular program you are running  and put it in $HOME/.config/firejail. A "quick and dirty" command line argument which might be enough is "--private-home=..." which can copy top-level files and directories into your sandbox filesystem. Note that there is a limit of 500MB on the size of the copied files, and copying the files will slow down the startup of your sandboxed application.
- **How can I run local applications through firejail?** This question is a bit general, since every application might need a different configuration (the whole reason why firejail is supplied with a whole library of profiles out of the box), and the configuration is dependent on exactly how you want to restrict the application (or not). However, I managed to run my application by installing it under a top-level directory in my home directory called $HOME/.local_fj and adding "private-home .local_fj" in the custom command profile (the 500MB limit mentioned above still applies). Another possibility might be using "whitelist ${HOME}/.local_fj/programInstallDir". In either case, ***make sure that any "noexec" commands do not block executing the program from the directory where it resides***. (Note: I am not an expert user of firejail --- it's almost certain that there are other ways to do this with which I am not familiar.)

Comment: Please add reference!